# Synchronize SharePoint 2013 Calender with Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-calendar, synchronisation, exchange-server

How to do two-way Synchronization between SharePoint 2013 Calender with Microsoft Exchange Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can try also some 3-rd party tools for it. Ex. from VirtoSoftware - http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint/exchange-group-calendar-web-part
or from Amrein - http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5778

Using these web parts you'll be able to synchronize your Exchange Calendar and SharePoint Calendar. And this configuring will work in two-ways. You can add multiple exchange calendars into one view if needed.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Would you please provide some explanation on your answer. Link only answers are not that good to read for other reader, as sometime links tend to break.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate an Exchange calendar with your SharePoint site by installing the Outlook Web App, My Calendar Web Part. With the My Calendar Web Part, you can maintain your Exchange calendar from OWA or Outlook, and calendar events will be synced to the SharePoint page where you install the Web Part. This feature is useful for sharing office hours, room schedules, resource bookings for equipment, events, etc.

- Go to the SharePoint site, and browse to the page where you will
  integrate the calendar.
- Click Page and Edit Page.
- Click Add a Web Part. Click the Outlook Web App category.
- Click the My Calendar Web Part, and click Add.
- Click "Open the tool pane" on the My Calendar Web Part.
- Enter https://spowa.uark.edu/owa/ in the Mail server address field.
- Enter the UARK email address for the account's Exchange calendar.
- Click OK.

https://techarticles.uark.edu/sharepoint/sharepoint_integrate_with_exchange_calendar/

Below link is for 2010 but you can try to amend the 2013 MyCalendar webpart.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh528520(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks.There is no proper guides or documents in MSDN for the Integration of Exchange-SharePoint 2013 Calendars.My Calender Web Part is Not available in SharePoint 2013.Instead of that,It gives only the "Outlook Web Access(OWA)" through the IFrame(Page view Controller).Does SharePoint 2013 provide any methods to integrate with MS Exchange through the C# Code/Webpart rather Than just a Webview? Is there any documents/guide from MSDN,That provides a clear guide to Integrate SharePoint  2013 Calendar with Exchange Calendar?